# How can I get rid of gtest compiler warning C4800 ('int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false'")

Tags: c++, windows-ce, googletest

I've inherited some unit test code (VS2008 c++ for a WinCE-based smart device) that uses gtest.  When I compile the unit tests I get all kinds of C4800 warnings about forcing ints into bools.  What's weird is that the only gtest calls in the module generating the warnings are to EXPECT_STREQ.

Is this a (minor) bug in gtest, it's doing EXPECT_STREQ in a way that confuses VS2008/WinCE?

We are using gtest version 1.6, does anyone know if version 1.7 works for WinCE?

==============

```
1>C:\googletest\include\gtest/internal/gtest-port.h(1031) : warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
1>        C:\googletest\include\gtest/internal/gtest-param-util.h(321) : see reference to function template instantiation 'Derived *testing::internal::CheckedDowncastToActualType<const testing::internal::ValuesInIteratorRangeGenerator<T>::Iterator,const testing::internal::ParamIteratorInterface<T>>(Base *)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Derived=const testing::internal::ValuesInIteratorRangeGenerator<ParamType>::Iterator,
1>            T=ParamType,
1>            Base=const testing::internal::ParamIteratorInterface<bool>
1>        ]
1>        C:\googletest\include\gtest/internal/gtest-param-util.h(314) : while compiling class template member function 'bool testing::internal::ValuesInIteratorRangeGenerator<T>::Iterator::Equals(const testing::internal::ParamIteratorInterface<T> &) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=ParamType
1>        ]
1>        C:\googletest\include\gtest/internal/gtest-param-util.h(276) : see reference to class template instantiation 'testing::internal::ValuesInIteratorRangeGenerator<T>::Iterator' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=ParamType
1>        ]
1>        C:\googletest\include\gtest/internal/gtest-param-util.h(275) : while compiling class template member function 'testing::internal::ParamIteratorInterface<T> *testing::internal::ValuesInIteratorRangeGenerator<T>::Begin(void) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=bool
1>        ]
1>        C:\googletest\include\gtest/gtest-param-test.h(314) : see reference to class template instantiation 'testing::internal::ValuesInIteratorRangeGenerator<T>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=ParamType
1>        ]
1>        C:\googletest\include\gtest/gtest-param-test.h(319) : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::internal::ParamGenerator<T> testing::ValuesIn<const T*>(ForwardIterator,ForwardIterator)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=bool,
1>            ForwardIterator=const bool *
1>        ]
1>        C:\googletest\include\gtest/internal/gtest-param-util-generated.h(99) : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::internal::ParamGenerator<T> testing::ValuesIn<T,2>(const T (&)[2])' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=bool
1>        ]
1>        C:\googletest\include\gtest/gtest-param-test.h(1221) : see reference to function template instantiation 'testing::internal::ValueArray2<T1,T2>::operator testing::internal::ParamGenerator<T>(void) const<bool>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T1=bool,
1>            T2=bool,
1>            T=bool
1>        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning C4800 is given when an int is put into a variable of type `bool`. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6801kcy.aspx) for warning C4800 states that it is a performance warning so you probably don't have to worry about it.

If you want hide the warning you can use MSVC's `#pragma warning(disable:4800)` to disable the warning.

So it would look like this

```
#pragma warning(disable:4800) //Disable the warning

... // Code that gives warning here

#pragma warning(default:4800) //Stop suppressing the warning
```

You can see the documentation for `#pragma warning` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx).